# Using sharp on serverless offline always fails

Tags: serverless, apple-m1, sharp

When I invoke any function in my serverless application I get an error as below. However, directly installing sharp give me no errors. also, when I run the tests sharp works perfectly.

Missing module": /build/Release/sharp-darwin-x64.node" exists in the node modules

```
Error:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-darwin-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /.esbuild/.build/src/functions/function1/handler.js
```

System:

- serverless offline
- node12 (x64)
- m1 chip (arm64)
- Serverless esbuild plugin used

solutions tried:

- delete and reinstall node modules
- install vips with brew
- https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2460#issuecomment-739110356
- https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2588#issuecomment-783254806

Comment: The way i solved it was to just use the serverless bundle which has a section for sharp in its documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-bundle

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform), try installing sharp.

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=darwin sharp
```

For AWS lambda deployment with **Sharp** module, the following worked for me when using **serverless**, **esbuild** and **serverless-esbuild**. Changed the serverless.yml file with the below configuration. It is basically telling esbuild to download sharp again with the following **--arch=x64 --platform=linux** considering your lambda uses x64 arch. Check [serverless-esbuild](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-esbuild) **packager** and **packagerOptions** options for more understanding.

```
esbuild:
    # keep existing configurations
    external:
      - sharp
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the `esbuild` solution working for local debugging. Instead, I modified my deployment scripts to always re-install the correct version of sharp before deploying.

The idea being I install the correct version of sharp before each scenario.

Here are my scripts in `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "npm run clean && npm install sharp && serverless invoke local --function annotate --path ./sampleEvent.json",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules/sharp",
    "sharp": "SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=glibc sharp",
    "deploy-prod": "npm run clean && npm run sharp && sls deploy --stage production",
    "deploy-dev": "npm run clean && npm run sharp && sls deploy --stage development"
  },
```